# Static int with array C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to static count my driver user. however it always give me same value instead

```
class Driver {
private:
  static int ID;
  string name;
public : 
  void displayDriver(string n) {
    cout << ID << endl;
  }
  void createDriver(string n) {
    name = n ;
    ID++;
  }
}

int Driver::id=0;

int main() {
  Driver driver[10];
  Driver[0].createDriver("first");
  Driver[1].createDriver("second");
  Driver[2].createDriver("first");                 
  Driver[0].displayDriver();
  Driver[1].displayDriver();
  Driver[2].displayDriver();
}
```

my expected output should be :

```
 1
 2
 3
```

but system shows me :

```
 3
 3
 3
```

Comment: You literally asked it to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private:
 static int ID;
```

Denotes that `ID` is shared among `Driver` instances. Any change to it (from `createDriver` in your current code) will be reflected in ALL instances. Don't use static field if you want each instance has its own unique field.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like I show here to get the results you expect. The idea is to keep the next counter in ID but every instance to have its own id that get initialized when you create the driver.

```
class Driver
{
  private:
     static int ID;
     int my_id;
     string name;
  public : 
  void displayDriver(string n)
  {
   cout << my_id << endl;
  }
  void createDriver(string n)
  {
    name = n ;
    my_id = ID++;
  }
}
int Driver::id=0;
int main
{
  Driver driver[10];
  Driver[0].createDriver("first");
  Driver[1].createDriver("second");
  Driver[2].createDriver("first");                 
  Driver[0].displayDriver();
  Driver[1].displayDriver();
  Driver[2].displayDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the value of ID gets incremented each time u createDriver("");

(no matter for which Driver[]) as it is a static variable

So u r incrementing ID progressively to 3 in first 3 lines
while displaying value of ID in next 3 lines

To get the expected output

I think u need to try it like this :

```
 Driver[0].createDriver("");
 Driver[0].displayDriver();
 Driver[1].createDriver("");
 .
 .  
 .
```

So on!

Note that all drivers have the same ID (static field).